# Playing sound using processing.sound.*; in java

Tags: java, audio, processing

I'm trying to figure out how to play a sound file that's in my data folder in my program. I wanted to use the processing.sound.*; library in Processing.

For example,

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.sound.*;

public class Sound {

public void setup() {

        size(800, 500);
        background(0);

}

public void draw() {
 file = new SoundFile(this, "happy.mp3")
 file.play();

}
```

is this supposed to work? it does not for me.

Comment: What does this code do? What's your question? Do you need all of that code to show how you're trying to play a sound, or can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: fixed! i'm just trying to play a sound file while my code runs

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much there, although I recommend loading the sound once in `setup()` rather than multiple times per second in `draw()`:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile file;

void setup() {
  size(800, 500);
  background(0);
  file = new SoundFile(this, "happy.mp3");
  file.play();
}

void draw() {

}
```

For more information checkout the [SoundFile example](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/SoundFile.html) and the [processing-sound library documentation](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/)

Comment: Thank you! I put it in setup(). But right now I'm getting an error that says "SoundFile" cannot be resolved into a type.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed the **processing-sound** library .Go to the  Contribution Manager via **Processing > Sketch > Import Library ... > Add Library ... >** and search for *processing-sound* by Processing Foundation, then press install.

Comment: No worries. If the answer was helpful, please vote and/or accept the answer as a solution. Thank you :)